# How to a get a seekbar to respond to methods

Tags: java, android, xml

I am creating a soundboard Android application in order to gain more of an understanding of what goes on under the hood of an application.

Currently have three seekbars in an activity called ChangeSounds. They control volume, panning and playback speed. I have coded a java file called SoundManager that handles these parameters. I am at the stage of linking the functionality of the soundManager to the ChangeSounds activity but I don't know how I should go about doing it. Should I use an intent? Or should I use a broadcast receiver? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ChangeSounds.java

```
package com.example.beatpadmaker;

// Importing necessary libraries
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ChangeSounds extends Activity {

// sets the layout to changesounds
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.changesounds);  
}
```

changesounds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/metalbackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Creates the settings text -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/titlesettings"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30sp" >
</TextView>

<!-- Creates the volume text -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/volumebar"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<!-- Creates the seekbar for volume -->
<SeekBar 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/VolBar1" 
    android:max="100" 
    android:progress="100">
</SeekBar>

<!-- Creates the balance text -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/balance"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<!-- Creates the seekbar for audio balance -->
<SeekBar 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:max="200" 
    android:id="@+id/BalBar" 
    android:progress="100">
</SeekBar>

<!-- Creates the speed text -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/speed"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</TextView>

<!-- Creates the seekbar for speed -->
<SeekBar 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/SpeedBar" 
    android:max="200" 
    android:progress="100">    
</SeekBar>

</LinearLayout>
```

SoundManager.java

```
package com.example.beatpadmaker;

//Importing necessary libraries
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class SoundManager {

//Initialising all variables    
private Context pContext;
private SoundPool sndPool;
private float rate = 1.0f;
private float masterVolume = 1.0f;
private float leftVolume = 1.0f;
private float rightVolume = 1.0f;
private float balance = 0.5f;

// Constructor that is used to setup the audio manager and store the  application context
public SoundManager(Context appContext)
{
  sndPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
  pContext = appContext;
}

// Load up a sound and return the id
public int load(int sound_id)
{
    return sndPool.load(pContext, sound_id, 1);
}

// Play a sound
public void play(int sound_id)
{
    sndPool.play(sound_id, leftVolume, rightVolume, 1, 0, rate);    
}   

// Set volume values based on existing volume value
public void setVolume(float vol)
{
    masterVolume = vol;

    if(balance < 1.0f)
    {
        leftVolume = masterVolume;
        rightVolume = masterVolume * balance;
    }
    else
    {
        rightVolume = masterVolume;
        leftVolume = masterVolume * ( 2.0f - balance );
    }

}

// Determine the speed of audio playback
public void setSpeed(float speed)
{
    rate = speed;

    // Speed of zero is invalid 
    if(rate < 0.01f)
        rate = 0.01f;

    // Speed has a maximum of 2.0
    if(rate > 2.0f)
        rate = 2.0f;
}

// Recalculate volume levels
public void setBalance(float balVal)
{
    balance = balVal;
    setVolume(masterVolume);
}

// Releases the soundpool's contents
public void unloadAll()
{
    sndPool.release();      
}

}
```

MainMenu.java

```
package com.example.beatpadmaker;

//Importing necessary libraries
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

//Initializing all variables as well as a tag string for testing my life cycle in logcat
private static final String TAG= MainMenu.class.getSimpleName();
SoundManager snd;
int sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4, sound5, sound6, sound7, sound8, sound9, sound10, sound11, sound12;
OnSeekBarChangeListener barChange;
OnClickListener buttonClick;

//Creating the layout
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu); 

Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called!");   

// Create an instance of our sound manger
snd = new SoundManager(getApplicationContext()); 

// Set volume rocker mode to media volume
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

// Load the samples from res/raw as oggs
sound1 = snd.load(R.raw.sound1);
sound2 = snd.load(R.raw.sound2);
sound3 = snd.load(R.raw.sound3);
sound4 = snd.load(R.raw.sound4);
sound5 = snd.load(R.raw.sound5);
sound6 = snd.load(R.raw.sound6);
sound7 = snd.load(R.raw.sound7);
sound8 = snd.load(R.raw.sound8);
sound9 = snd.load(R.raw.sound9);
sound10 = snd.load(R.raw.sound10);
sound11 = snd.load(R.raw.sound11);
sound12 = snd.load(R.raw.sound12);

// Create a seek bar handler
barChange = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
    {   

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
    {  

    }
    //Creating the three cases for the different seekbars to get the progress of volume, balance and speed
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 
    {
        switch (seekBar.getId())
        {
         case R.id.VolBar1:
             snd.setVolume((float)progress/100.0f);
             break;

         case R.id.BalBar:
             snd.setBalance((float)progress/100.0f);
             break;

         case R.id.SpeedBar:
             snd.setSpeed((float)progress/100.0f);
             break;
        }
    }
};

}

// Button listener assigned in XML layout
public void clickHandler(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId(); 
    // Use the button id to determine which sample should be played

    switch (id)
    {
     case R.id.button1:
     snd.play(sound1);
     break;

     case R.id.button2:
     snd.play(sound2);
     break;

     case R.id.button3:
     snd.play(sound3);
     break;       

     case R.id.button4:
     snd.play(sound4);
     break;       

     case R.id.button5:
     snd.play(sound5);
     break;       

     case R.id.button6:
     snd.play(sound6);
     break;

     case R.id.button7:
     snd.play(sound7);
     break; 

     case R.id.button8:
     snd.play(sound8);
     break;

     case R.id.button9:
     snd.play(sound9);
     break; 

     case R.id.button10:
     snd.play(sound10);
     break; 

     case R.id.button11:
     snd.play(sound11);
     break; 

     case R.id.button12:
     snd.play(sound12);
     break;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate(), get a reference to each seekbar using

`SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volume);`

Then set the listener on it.

`bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(barChangeListener);`

Make sure if you do this way you define the listener.

```
private OnSeekBarChangeListener barChangeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    // implement abstract methods 
}
```

Comment: i have attempted to implement this but my application no longer loads, is there a specific order to i need to implement this in? i am not sure i have implemented  your code correctly .